# SimpleTcpClient send single byte and receive single byte without delimiter

Tags: c#

I have written a simple TCP IP app using SimpleTcpClient.
I only need to send single bytes to an electronic device and the device then either send a single byte back or nothing at all.
Timing is important so I also need to send bytes repeatedly as fast as possible and also time this.

The app works to some extend when using "Client.WriteLineAndGetReply" but then I have the annoying delimiter hex 13 that I do not want to send to my electronics but due to "Client.WriteLineAndGetReply" have no choice.  Using this my device responds and I can see the return in my "textBoxReceiveByte".

When I use "Client.Write(bytes);" I can see that I am sending only the single byte I want to but now I am not reading the single byte back from my electronics.

My code:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch sendStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        ToolTip toolTiptextBoxMessage = new ToolTip();
        TimeSpan time;
        SimpleTcpClient Client;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonConnect.Enabled = false;
            Client.Connect(textBoxHost.Text,
                     Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPort.Text));
            buttonDisconnect.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            //Client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            Client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            textBoxReceiveByte.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                textBoxReceiveByte.Text += e.MessageString;
            });
        }

        private void buttonTCPIPSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string sendString = textBoxMessage.Text.Replace(" ",
            //       string.Empty);
            //textBoxMessage.Text = sendString;

            //byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBoxMessage.Text);
            byte[] bytes = { 0 };

            sendStopWatch.Stop();
            sendStopWatch.Reset();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                sendStopWatch.Start();

                //Client.WriteLineAndGetReply(textBoxMessage.Text,
                //    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
                Client.Write(bytes);

                sendStopWatch.Stop();
                if (checkBoxReportOnOff.Checked)
                {
                    time = sendStopWatch.Elapsed;
                    textBoxStatus.Text += "Time elapsed (ms): " +
                          time.TotalSeconds * 1000 + "\r\n";
                }
                sendStopWatch.Reset();
            }        
        }

        private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxStatus.Text = "";
        }

        private void textBoxMessage_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTiptextBoxMessage.Show("Hex byt must be two characters with
             spaces inbetween. Example: 01 13 14 15 16 10", textBoxMessage);
        }

        private void checkBoxBytesSendAll_CheckedChanged(object sender,
                 EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void checkBoxDelayEach_CheckedChanged(object sender,
                           EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBoxDelayEach.Checked)
            {
                textBoxDelayAfterEach.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxDelayAfterEach.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBoxDelayAll_CheckedChanged(object sender,
                      EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBoxDelayAll.Checked)
            {
                textBoxDelayAfterAll.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxDelayAfterAll.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void groupBoxByteSend_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTiptextBoxMessage.Show("When checked all bytes in HEX text
                  box will be send. Else only first byte.", textBoxMessage);
        }

        private void buttonCommsCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] bytes = { 0 };

            //Client.WriteLineAndGetReply("0", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            Client.Write(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question?

Comment: Thanks.
After going from "Client.WriteLineAndGetReply" to Client.Write(bytes); I am not getting the byte coming back from my electronic device.  How do I read the byte coming back ?  Also keeping in mind that time is important...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SimpleTcp (it's not part of .NET), but since nobody answered, I'll take a shot. From looking at the [source code](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP/blob/master/SimpleTCP/SimpleTcpClient.cs), it looks like the only way to read a single byte is to get the `TcpClient` directly and use its stream:

```
byte [] toRead = new byte[1];
NetworkStream stream = Client.TcpClient.GetStream();
stream.Read(toRead, 0, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works however that makes another problem.  If my device does not send a byte back in return (this is enabled or disabled on the device) it slows down everything a lot.
Trying Client.TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 1; and/or 
            NetworkStream stream = Client.TcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.ReadTimeout = 1; seems to have no effect.


it seems to still wait about 200ms hoping some byte comes back...